# Visual Studio 2010 C++ - "Create new project platforms" box DISABLED

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, project, platform

I have a trouble when creating a new (x64) solution platform.

Visual Studio 2010 C++ => Type or select the new platform

I currently cannot check the "Create new project platforms" box as you can see below.

[image: screenshot]

What do I have to do ? I have uninstalled the visual studio and installed it again together with windows 7.1 SDK (installation order: first windows 7.1 SDK then the visual studio).

Thanks.

Comment: Type the name of the new platform in the edit control first, then it should enable the checkbox.

Comment: It did not enable :\ I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It's been a while, maybe not remembering correctly, but wasn't there an install option for other platforms when installing VS2010?  I know there's one for IA64, but not sure about the X64 option which presumably you're more interesting in.

Comment: Yup, it was still an option for VS2010, off by defaut.  Rerun setup to add them, re-apply service pack.